# How to exclude folder/file from build in Visual Studio Code (c#/.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I used to work with Visual Studio on my .Net Core projects but I switched over to Visual Studio Code due to performance and usability reasons.

What I'm missing is a way to exclude folders/files from compiliation/build in c#. Is there a way to do so in VS code?

Thank you,
Andy

Comment: Have you tried:
<None Include="fileName" /> ?

Comment: If you don't try. Please, edit your *.csproj file and add <None Include="fileName" /> in any existing or new <ItemGroup />
or if you need to exclude all files in folder and subfolders:
<None Include="FolderName\\**\\*" />

Comment: I tried <None Include=..." but it does not seem to work.
`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="FolderToExclude\fileToExclude.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>`